# dplyr::mutate new columns based on a second (filtered) dataframe

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse, dplyr

I have 2 data frames:

df1:

```
a
s1
s2
s3
s4
```

df2:

```
a    b
s1    w
s1    x
s4    y
s2    z
s4    x
```

I want to append to df1 as many columns as unique values are in df2$b (w, x, y, z), and for each df1$a and new column add a 1 if df2$a has a row associating them. This is cumbersome to explain, maybe showing the desired output is better:

```
a    w    x    y    z
s1    1    1    0    0
s2    0    0    0    1
s3    0    0    0    0
s4    0    1    1    0
```

I have tried

```
for (col_name in unique(df2$b)){
  df1 %<>%
    mutate(!!as.character(col_name) := ifelse(col_name %in% filter(df2,
                                                                   a == df1$a)$b,
                                          yes = 1,
                                          no = 0))
}
```

But this does not work, and I guess the problem lies in the

```
a == df1$a
```

bit, but I do not know which is the proper syntaxis for this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can use `table(df2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
newdf <- df1 %>% full_join(df2) %>%
  mutate(val=ifelse(!is.na(b),1,NA),
         b=ifelse(is.na(b),'Emp',b)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = b,values_from=val,
              values_fill=0,names_sort = T) %>%
  select(-Emp)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  a         w     x     y     z
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 s1        1     1     0     0
2 s2        0     0     0     1
3 s3        0     0     0     0
4 s4        0     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `table` in `base R` (assuming that we wanted the row for all the values from 'a' column in 'df1', convert the 'a' column of 'df2' to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` values of 'a' from 'df1'

```
table(transform(df2, a = factor(a, levels = unique(df1$a))))
```

-output

```
# b
#a    w x y z
#  s1 1 1 0 0
#  s2 0 0 0 1
#  s3 0 0 0 0
#  s4 0 1 1 0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(a = c("s1", "s1", "s4", "s2", "s4"), b = c("w", 
"x", "y", "z", "x")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: This works, but it returns a table instead of a data frame

Comment: @Miguel I would wrap with `as.data.frame.matrix(table(transform(df2, a = factor(a, levels = unique(df1$a)))))`

Comment: Yes that works, thanks but I already accepted the other answer that includes dplyr

Comment: @Miguel it's okay.  Your question is also related to dplyr and that makes sense. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` and `tidyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df3 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  complete(a = df1$a, b) %>%
  spread(b, value, fill = 0)

df4 <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df3, by = "a")
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- tibble(
  a = paste0("s", 1:4)
)

df2 <- read.table(text = "
a    b
s1    w
s1    x
s4    y
s2    z
s4    x",
                header = TRUE)
```